# Android IllegalStateException on orientation change in getView of SimplecursorAdapter

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, illegalstateexception

I get a IllegalStateException when changing orientation. I have a listView using a *SimpleCursorAdapter* and a ContentProvider.
Any ideas what causes this exception?

**EDIT**

I must've changed something since I only see the exception when selecting an item from the actionbar spinner and then change the orientation.
the action bar spinner has three items: Show All, Show Date, Show Location

When the user selects one, it queries the database (see onNavigationItemSelected()). I tried closing the cursor in onStop() but that didn't solve the problem.
Where would be the right place to close it?

in MainActivity:

```
 private  Cursor mCursor = null;

 public void onCreate() {
    mSimpleCursorAdapter = new SpecialAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.row,
            null,
            //cursor,
            PROJECTION,
            new int[] { R.id.titleID, R.id.dateTimeOrLocationID1 , R.id.dateTimeOrLocationID2 },
            CursorAdapter.NO_SELECTION);

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    mListView.setAdapter(mSimpleCursorAdapter);


    mOnNavigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {

          @Override
          public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long itemId) {

              switch(position) { 
              case 0:
                  mCursor = getContentResolver().query(ReminderContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, null);
                  break;
              case 1:

                  mCursor = getContentResolver().query(ReminderContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, " Date NOT NULL", null, null);
                  break;
              case 2:
                  mCursor = getContentResolver().query(ReminderContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, " Address NOT NULL", null, null);
                  break;
              default:
                  break;
              }
            getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, MainActivity.this);
            return true;
          }
        };
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(this, ReminderContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, null);
    return loader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mSimpleCursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mSimpleCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

SimpleCursorAdapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Cursor mCursor = (Cursor) getItem(position); // exception
    if(mCursor != null)
    {
              ........
    }
 }
```

**EDIT**

```
E/ACRA    ( 3348): com.example.locationreminder fatal error : attempt to re-open an already-closed   object: SQLiteQuery: SELECT _id, Title, Date, Address, Radius, Repetition FROM reminder
E/ACRA    ( 3348): java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery: SELECT _id, Title, Date, Address, Radius, Repetition FROM reminder
E/ACRA    ( 3348):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
E/ACRA    ( 3348):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:58)
E/ACRA    ( 3348):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:151)
E/ACRA    ( 3348):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.onMove(SQLiteCursor.java:124)
E/ACRA    ( 3348):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:213)
E/ACRA    ( 3348):  at android.database.CursorWrapper.moveToPosition(CursorWrapper.java:162)
E/ACRA    ( 3348):  at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getItem(CursorAdapter.java:207)
E/ACRA    ( 3348):  at com.example.locationreminder.SpecialAdapter.getView(SpecialAdapter.java:51)
E/ACRA    ( 3348):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2271)
E/ACRA    ( 3348):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
```

Comment: I added the exception log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is the reason of failure, but there is clearly bug in your code: you try to mix manual cursor management with loader. In `OnNavigationItemSelected` you call `changeCursor`. There are several problems:

1. You load data in UI thread, loaders exist to avoid this
2. `changeCursor` closes old cursor. But this cursor is owned by loader, you shouldn't close it, it will be closed by loader after it calls `OnLoadFinished`
3. It is not clear where manually created cursors are closed.

What you should do in `OnNavigationItemSelected` is to restart loader with new query parameters.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the code and removed changeCursor. The exception is gone now, but the listview doesn't update anymore even though I added getLoaderManager().restartLoader(). What am I missing?